# AVR32 UC3 USB data loss in cdc device mode

Tags: c#, c, avr, avr32, atmel-uc3

I need to transfer data from AT32 UC3 microcontroller ADC to PC via USB. I check work of ADC and PDCA in MCU of filling the buffer, and it works was perfect without data loosing. But when I send data from USB some bytes are lost. I do not know, why this happens.
I write simple programms to send some data from MCU to PC and check this data. In MCU I fill buffer with numbers from 0,1,2.. to 255 continuously, then send buffer via USB to PC, and check content of this buffer. So, some numbers are different from original data. Some bytes are lost. I using EVK1100 in CDC device mode.

*AVR code:*

```
#include <asf.h>
#include "conf_usb.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 32

int main(void){

   irq_initialize_vectors();
   cpu_irq_enable();

   sysclk_init();

   udc_start();
   udc_attach();

   char pbuf[BUF_SIZE];
   for(int i=0; i<BUF_SIZE; i++){
       pbuf[i] = (char)i;
   }

   while (true) {
       udi_cdc_write_buf(pbuf, BUF_SIZE);
   }
}
```

*C# code:*

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.IO.Ports;

  namespace acc_tester
  {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            int N = 32;

            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();

            serialPort.PortName = "COM6";

            serialPort.Open();

            byte[] buf = new byte [N];

            for (int n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
                serialPort.Read(buf, 0, N);

                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    if (buf[i] != (byte)(buf[0] + i)) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Data Lost. n =" + n.ToString() + " i=" + i.ToString());
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            serialPort.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Stop");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of my C# program is:

*Data Lost. n =257 i=31*

*Data Lost. n =385 i=31*

*Data Lost. n =641 i=31*

*Data Lost. n =257 i=31*
and etc.

Please, help me solve the problem.

Comment: what framework version, what compiler and which driver are you using? Also what OS on PC you got. Also check the USB port (should be 2.0 not 3.0 just to be sure). In case of Windows on slower machines (like notebooks) if OS is too busy (like with gfx) then USB CDC bulk transfer tends to lose sync and create pauses in transfer in driver layer. If your MCU side is not designed to handle it anything can occur (but I never saw loss of data before)

Answer (score 0):

`SerialPort.Read` reads **at most** `N` (32) bytes, it depends on how many bytes are in the input buffer ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.110).aspx)). `Read` returns the amount of bytes read.

To read chunk of data of length `N` you should buffer yourself the data and only check the content when you reach `N` bytes. Eg.

```
while (true) {
    var bytesInBuffer = 0;
    bytesInBuffer += serialPort.Read(buf, bytesInBuffer, N - bytesInBuffer);
    if (bytesInBuffer == N) {
        // Here the buffer is ready
        bytesInBuffer = 0; // reset the counter
    }
}
```

Comment: In Atmel AVR4901 in table 4-2 showed the following endpoint types: control, interrupt, bulk and isochronous. But only bulk mode has been guarateed the transfer of data. I need to know, in which mode works CDC device mode and how to switch it to bulk mode CDC device in ASF.